# How print python method documentation using inspect or __doc__ method

Tags: python

I have following code :

```
import os
import imp
import sys
import inspect
import urlparse
from cgi import escape

def get_module(ClassName, Path):
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(ClassName, [Path])
    module_loaded = imp.load_module(ClassName, fp, pathname, description)
    return module_loaded


def get_class_members(className):
    print "Members of  "+str(className)
    member_functions = inspect.getmembers(className,    predicate=inspect.ismethod)
    for each_item in member_functions:
        print each_item[0].__doc__

def get_all_classes(path, module):

    module_loaded = None
    sys.path.append(path)

    module_loaded = get_module(module, path)

    if None != module_loaded:
        class_list = module_loaded.get_all_classes()
        print "classes are "+str(class_list)
        return class_list




def main():
    class_list = get_all_classes('.', 'Class_Interface_File')
    for each_class in class_list:
        temp_module = get_module(each_class, '.')
        my_class = getattr(temp_module, each_class)
        instance = my_class()
        get_class_members(instance)
        print "-----------"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Class_Interface_file returns a list of classnames example ['Social', 'Audio']
I have issue here in method get_class_members. I want to print the comments for each member function I discover through inspect.getmembers. I dono how to concat className with value of each_item.

or is it possible to directly print documentation of member functions which comes from each_item ?

please help on this.

Comment: You seem to be re-implementing the builtin `help` function ... Is there a reason :-)?

Comment: can I directly use help on each_item[0] ? which is the member function name..

Comment: I tried to use help(each_item[0]) but it returns no documentation available for function. Where as I have documentation embedded with in """ """

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, did some playing around with your code....

I have a class Triangle in a module triangle with some methods.

```
>>>import inspect
>>>import triangle
>>>mems = inspect.getmembers(triangle.Triangle)
>>>mems
[('__doc__', None), ('__init__','<unboound method.....>), etc)]
```

`getmembers()` returns a list of tuples. 
So in your code, looping through this, you're asking for `each_item[0].__doc__`, [0] refers to the string containing the name of the function. So that line returns just the `__doc__` of string objects. Changing this to [1] will return the `__doc__` for the actual method:

```
>>>mems[3][0]  #the name of the function itself
'drawEquilateral'
>>>#here I reference the second tuple element of the fourth member
...
>>>mems[3][1].__doc__
'draw an equilateral triangle'
>>>"Method %s:  %s" %(mems[3][0], mems[3][1].__doc__)
'Method drawEquilateral: draw an equilateral triangle'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just have one question. like I have a helper class which returns all the member functions as list of strings. Can I use __doc__ on these strings types ? your answer will be very helpfull.

Comment: if you call `'any string here'.__doc__` it will return the documentation on string objects in general, so if you're trying to print out the docstrings of the actual functions named in your list, you'll have to do a bit more work (but not hard using `getmembers()`). can be of more help in chat